# How to bind route with controller with Symfony2 Routing component

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex

I want to use a standalone Symfony2 Routing component in my small site. I've created this according to documentation and some examples:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$routeTest = new Symfony\Component\Routing\Route('/route-test', array('controller' => 'test'));

$routes = new Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection();
$routes->add('test', $routeTest);

$context = new Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);

$matcher = new Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher($routes, $context);
$matcher->match($request->getPathInfo());
```

I don't understand how I should call my controller test, that I've passed to the Route constructor. As a result I want to get something like Silex Route matching:

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
   return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
});
```

And sorry for my english...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$matcher->match()` returns<sup>[[1](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L90-91)]</sup> the attributes of the matching route<sup>[[2](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L167)]</sup> (including a special `_route` attribute containing the route name <sup>[[3](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php#L171-189)]</sup>).

The `controller` default is included in the attributes too, so you can easily access it and then use something like [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call-user-func) to call the controller:

```
// ...
$attributes = $match->match($request->getPathInfo());

$controllerResult = call_user_func($attributes['controller']);
```